# Unable to align two floating divs horizontally

Tags: css, html

I'm very new to XHTML and CSS and I can't get the floats to work. Somehow I keep ending up with "**fondo_header**" below  and on the right hand side of **"wrapper"**.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="header">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="figure">
                    <img src="images/logo_2nd_225x1182_forWeb.jpg" alt="Logo" width="225" height="118">

            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="fondo_header">
                <div id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#header{
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
       }

#fondo_header{
       width: 74%;
       float: right;
       background: url(images/header.jpg);

       }

#wrapper{
    width: 250px;
    /*float:left;*/
    height:auto;
    background-color:#f2dfce;
        }
```

I need to put **"wrapper"** and **"fondo_header"** right next to each other. The width for all divs should be correct, I've also tried pixels, different widths, adding margins, padding, different floating styles and way too many things but nothing works.

I've tried IE9, Chrome and FF with the same results. Margins and paddings have been reset.

I'm pretty sure I'm overlooking something pretty obvious at this this point.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You will have a better chance of receiving an answer if you link your code on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: You have a fixed width for the wrapper but not for fondo_header.  What do you want it to do to fondo_header when there isn't room for it?  move it down?  keep it there and just overflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case ur using floating 
the floating element's width should not exceed width of container else one will go on the second line

in ur case 74% for fondo_header + 240px for wrapper is greater then width of header
u can fix that by setting width of wrapper to 26%

or setting static values for both

Comment: Even with enough width he has his float left commented and they will go onto the next line since the Div is a block display.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hadn't realized they were wider than their container's width.

Answer (score 0):

You have to float both `#fondo_header` and `#wrapper` to the left. And when you float elements you have to set `overflow: hidden` on the parent element, so it fits its content's height.

Take a look at this, it will help you understand floats better: [All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).
**Edit:** Floating `#wrapper` to the left and `#fondo_header` to the right also works.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work alright for me as long as the header is small enough to fit.  Are you sure you're giving each element enough room?  Using percentages for width of one element and pixels for the other are going to give you different results depending on your screen width.

```
#header{
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
       }

#fondo_header{
       width: 30%;
       float: right;
       background: url(images/header.jpg);

       }

#wrapper{
    width: 250px;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#f2dfce;
        }​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ARvw3/